# Why is my taxonomy template not shown?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, templates

I have created a custom taxonomy for my site called `projects` with a matching template called `taxonomy-projects.php`. The problem is that when I browse to `http://mysite.com/projects` the template is not triggered, `index.php` is, but when I browse to `http://mysite.com/projects/someterm` the template shows up just fine.

How can have my template displayed when I browse to `http://mysite.com/projects`?

Before you ask. Yes, I'm aware that I need to clear the rewrite rules before changes are made. I do this by saving the Permalink settings in the admin.

This is how I've created my custom taxonomy:

```
$args = array(
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => "Categories",
        'singular_name' => "Category",
        'search_items' => "Search Categories",
        'popular_items' => "Popular Categories",
        'all_items' => "All Categories",
        'parent_item' => "Parent Category",
        'parent_item_colon' => "Parent Category:",
        'edit_item' => "Edit Category",
        'update_item' => "Update Category",
        'add_new_item' => "Add New Category",
        'new_item_name' => "New Category Name",
    ),
    'hierarchical' => TRUE,
    'label' => 'Categories',
    'query_var' => TRUE,
    'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'projects'
    ),
);

register_taxonomy('projects', 'project', $args);
```

**UPDATE:**

I've traced the output of `$wp_query->get_queried_object()` on each page and when I browse to a page with a term, such as `http://mysite.com/projects/commercial` I get the following output:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [term_id] => 4
    [name] => Commercial
    [slug] => commercial
    [term_group] => 0
    [term_taxonomy_id] => 8
    [taxonomy] => projects
    [description] => 
    [parent] => 0
    [count] => 1
)
```

However, when I browse to `http://mysite.com/projects` the output is nothing.

I'm failing to understand what I'm doing wrong. How can I make the `taxonomy-projects.php` shown when I browse to `http://mysite.com/projects`?

Comment: I had similar problem and was solved when I visited the permalinks settings page in wordpress admin. ( just visited the page, nothing else ! )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use archive-projects.php to work mysite.com/projects, that's all

Comment: Bit late but thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried it with the permalink base in the url? It defaults to "category".
http://mysite.com/category/projects
The WP codex is quoted below.

> 'with_front' - allowing permalinks to be prepended with front base -
>   defaults to true

You would need to set 'with_front' to false for http://mysite.com/projects to work.

Also when you have only 'projects' in your url it is hard for WP to know if it is a post, page, custom post type, taxonomy, etc.

Comment: Sorry for my delayed response. The "category/projects" suggestion doesn't work, it falls back to index.php. I've tried the 'with_front' and it doesn't make a difference set to either true or false. I'm a bit at a loss at the moment.

Comment: My other thought is that you register the taxonomy this way: `register_taxonomy('projects', 'project', $args);` which means you have a custom post type named "project". If you don't have, 'project' should be 'post'.

Comment: Yes. I have created a custom post type named "project". I'm still struggling to make this work. Either I'm doing something really wrong here or something in WP is fundamentally broken.

Answer (score 0):

Did you flush the rewrite rules?  Add this after your custom taxonomy code:

```
    flush_rewrite_rules();
```

You only need to have this run once when you make a change.  Comment it out after it works.